# How to rerun a function (that runs when component is mounted) when the redux store is changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

As in the title, I have a React component, the relevant part of which looks a bit like this as of now:

```
class myComponent {
  fetchSomething = async() => {
    this.setState({data: fetch(props.id)})
  }
  componentDidMount(){
   this.fetchSomething()
  }

  render() {
    {data}
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
 ...
  return { id }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(myComponent);
```

I need to basically rerun the `fetchSomething` function whenever the `id` property in redux store changes, since I want to see the changes as soon as it happens, and I don't want to have to mount the component again.

Comment: you can try life cycle method [`componentWillReceiveProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops)

Answer (score 0):

you can try using `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
 if(prevProps.id !== this.props.id) {
      this.fetchSomething();
 }
}
```

More on componentDidUpdate or other useful lifecycle methods [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would this be better than remounting myComponent by changing its key? Because I've just tried that and it seems to work

Comment: What do you mean by changing it's key

Comment: You can pass a prop called 'key' into the component. If this 'key' prop is changed, React remounts the component.

Comment: Well if in the key prop you're passing the `id` field then it should work yes. But keep in mind that if you have more props then your component will still be remounted if another prop is updated. So I would say using `componentDidUpdate` and check whether your `id` prop has changed is safest.